# how to edit record values in modal window

Tags: visualforce

how to pass contact id in iframe tage to open contact edited values having visual force page.

my code is

```
<apex:page controller="modalrecords" showHeader="false">
  <div class="container">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
          <div class="record"><apex:column headerValue="firstname" value="{!c.firstname}"/></div>
          <apex:column headerValue="lastname" value="{!c.lastname}" />
          <apex:column headerValue="email" value="{!c.email}"/>
          <div class="editButton">
            <apex:column headervalue="edit">
              <apex:commandButton value="edit" action="{!edit}"  rerender="tstpopup" />
            </apex:column>
          </div>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
      </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
  </div>

  <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
      <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
        <iframe src ="saverecords?id={!con.id}" width="500" height="500"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>

    <style type="text/css">
    .custPopup{
        background-color: white;                          
        border-radius:3px;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to change so the popup
        displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set
        margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can add
        the height property for a fixed size pop up if you want.*/
        width: 250px;
        margin-left: -150px;
        top:200px;
    }
    .popupBackground{
        background-color:black;
        opacity: 0.20;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
    .header{
 color:#CC0033;
font-size:19px;            
    }
</style>  

</apex:page>
```

apex:

```
public class modalrecords{
  public boolean displayPopup {get; set;} 
  public contact con{get;set;}
  public modalrecords(){
  }
  public list<contact> getcontacts(){
    return[select id,firstname,lastname,email from contact where (owner.id =: userinfo.getuserid())];
  }
  public void edit(){
    displayPopup = true;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your con variable is never assigned a value. Here is something you can do.

Add a variable in your Apex class.

```
 public String conId{get;set;}
```

And modify your commandButton to pass the related row's contact ID.

```
<apex:commandButton value="edit" action="{!edit}"  rerender="tstpopup" >
            <apex:param name="conId"
                value="{!c.Id}"
                assignTo="{!conId}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

It will save the related Id in conId and then pass this conId to our saverecords page.

```
<iframe src ="apex/saverecords?id={!conId}" width="500" height="500"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is where you're having problems:

```
<iframe src ="saverecords?id={!con.id}" width="500" height="500"/>
```

My assumpotion is that `saverecords` is the VF page you want to put into your iframe.

Easiest, since you're in VF, is to maybe use the `$Page` global variable. So like this:

```
<iframe src ="{!$Page.saverecords}?id={!con.id}" width="500" height="500"/>
```

On the server side, this should resolve to the correct URL to invoke the page.

I would think this would work, but if, for some reason, it didn't, you could always just use the relative URL to visualforce which always begins with `apex`, so:

```
<iframe src ="apex/saverecords?id={!con.id}" width="500" height="500"/>
```

Myself, personally, I'll always use the global variables as more safe references to items, than hard coded URLs. But now I'm devolving into opinion, perhaps...

Comment: in this id place "{!con.id}" i cant get current id value but i need to get current id .. please tell me the solution for that